# Need help in getting attributes for mobile device in Adobe CQ 5 Mobile Application Development

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, aem

I am new to CQ 5 Mobile Application Development what I want to achieve is,
When a mobile device send the request to the page it captures the attributes of mobile like mobile browser, mobile browser version, mobile OS and mobile OS version.
I want to LOG this information and in later stage use this to categorize them in different Device Group and render different components in different device groups.

**Note I have already went through some of these links**
[CQ5 Mobile Development Docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/mobile.html)

http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/cq/adobe-cq-5-5-mobile-improvements/
http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/help_doc.php

I have tried this code which throws Null Pointer Exception, since device has null value.
Correct me if I am doing wrong somewhere

```
SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = this.request.getSlingRequest();
    Device device = slingRequest.adaptTo(Device.class);
    Map<String, String> deviceAttributes = device.getAttributes();
    LOG.info("Request is sent from Device with OS"+deviceAttributes.get("device_os"));
```

Here is the way I am testing this code, whenever a request is sent to the page which has this component which logs the attributes of the mobile device from one of the emulator, I check my LOG Files that

Please help me out if I am going wrong in the code or method to get the mobile device's attributes. Please let me know if you need more details on this.

Regards,
Yash

Hi Here is the Stack Trace for this :

```
Caused by: org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /apps/companyname/components/content/mobilebreadcrum/mobilebreadcrum.jsp at line 5
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspExceptionInternal(JspServletWrapper.java:571)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:496)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:448)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspServletWrapperAdapter.service(JspServletWrapperAdapter.java:59)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:173)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:84)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:388)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:358)
... 147 more Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'modelName' on type com.companyname.www.components.content.mobilebreadcrumb.MobileBreadCrum
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:66)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:53)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:97)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:923)
at org.apache.jsp.apps.companyname.components.content.mobilebreadcrum.mobilebreadcrum_jsp._jspService(mobilebreadcrum_jsp.java:160)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
... 152 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.companyname.www.components.content.mobilebreadcrumb.MobileBreadCrum.getModelName(MobileBreadCrum.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:62)
... 160 more
```

The JSP Code is :

```
<%@include file="/apps/companyname/components/global.jsp"%><ct:component
className="com.companyname.www.components.content.mobilebreadcrumb.MobileBreadCrum"
name="mobilebreadcrum" />${mobilebreadcrum.modelName}
```

The Java Code is:

```
    public String getModelName() {
    SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = this.request.getSlingRequest();
    String resourceType = slingRequest.getResource().getResourceType();
    String resourceSuperType = slingRequest.getResource().getResourceSuperType();
    LOG.info("RESOURCE TYPE:"+resourceType);
    LOG.info("RESOURCE SUPER TYPE:"+resourceSuperType);
    Device device = request.getCurrentPage().adaptTo(Device.class);
    device.getAttributes();
    return modelName;
}
```

Please let me know if you want anything else

Regards,
Yash

Answer (score 0):

Could you please go to /system/console/adapters and make sure that there is appropriate adapter SlingHttpServletRequest → Device?
I'd start diagnosis from there. In my case corresponding row looks like this:

Adaptable Class: org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest

Adapter Class: com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.api.device.DeviceGroup, com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.api.device.DeviceGroupList, com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.api.device.Device

Providing bundle: com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-mobile-core (190)

Thanks,
Max.

Comment: Thanks for replying Maksim, it shows the same for me in system/console/adapters also the Bundle is active without any errors. Let me know if you find something wrong other than this.Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey Yash, just to confirm a couple of points so I can try to help you: do you use real device, 3rd party emulator or built-in CQ emulator? Where do you send your request (in case of one of first two options): directly to publishing instance, directly yo authoring instance, dispatcher or some other proxy?

Comment: Hi Maksim , I am using built-in-CQ emulator on my authoring instance , basically I have this component deployed and added to the Mobile Group, I am testing it in Geometrix mobile website, I open a page from the website drag my component where I am trying to capture the mobile's (emulator's) OS Version and other attributes in the LOG files as mentioned in the Question.

Comment: Hey Yash, sorry for late responce. Could you paste exception stacktrace you refer to? Package with component you use would be great so I could see code and properties and inheritance from foundation components.

Comment: Hi Maksim, Sorry for the late response, you can check the stack trace, in code I am using com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.api.device.Device; package for adapting To Mobile.I guess that is what you want to check for , let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

To do this u should use real device, not an emulator. To detect a device CQ looks at user-agent data in the request, so when u open a page on desktop browser u send request with not-a-mobile device user-agent data. To test this feature u can use something like user agent switcher (eg [for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg)), but in that case CQ will not use and draw an emulator wrapper cause it will assume that u use a mobile device.
Now I think how to combine right user-agent and drawing an emulator on desktop. Will post by results.

Comment: Hi Dzianis I tried hitting the Page by switching to Android User Agent, also CQ renders the emulator for this in the authroing environment,also I tried the same with real mobile device and it does shows the emulator, but the code doesn't works and shows the same Stack Trace as I have edited in the post.

Comment: It's weird. I switched to iPhone user-agent in chrome, and code work properly, but without rendering of emulator as i said, didn't try with real device yet.

Comment: I am looking at your code and it looks strange. If "modelName" is a class field do u have a "setter" for it, or if u have only "getModelName" method where is code line with something like modelName = device.getAttributes().get("device_os"));

Comment: Hi Dzianis , basicaly I am doing modelName=device.getAttributes().get("device_os") in the "getModelName" method, I know this is not the right place and right way to do it, but the exception is thrown at the place device.getAttributes(), since sling is not adapting to the Device class. Let me know if you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

thinking a step above, if you are able to fix this issue how you gonna serve requests? will you always serve requests from publish Aem server or you want to utilize Dispatcher caching?
As your code is identifying device on server side, i doubt you would be able to leverage dispatcher caching. can you think of identifying device on apache level and add selectors in request.
eg. if request if coming from iphone5, then write a rewrite rule on apache to check User agent header and add a selector
http://somesite.com/my/page/url.html to http://somesite.com/my/page/url.iphone.html

if request coming from ipad then add other selector
http://somesite.com/my/page/url.ipad.html

Dispatcher will create different cache for different selectors and will start serving pages from cache.

In your component, you can implement different views for different selector.

Its just a thought, please rethink ...